# I can't run any script in vscode: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logger')

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi guys, when I try to run any code in VSCODE, error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logger) pops up.

I tried to reboot my PC, but it seems helpless.

My vscode is up to date.

Anybody else has a similar problem? I can't run a single code...

Comment: Please include your code and errors in text and not as an image.

Comment: I think this has to do with a recent update of VSC - same issue here ...

Comment: Can you please share the logs from the developer tools console?